# error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
factory Book.fromMap(Map map) => Book(
      id: map['id'],
      bookName: map['bookName'],
      authorName: map['authorName'],
      publishedDate: map['publishedDate']);
```

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> streamListDocument = _database
        .getBookListApi(booksRef)
        .map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs);

Stream<Iterable<Book>> streamListBook = streamListDocument.map((event) =>
        event.map((docSnap) => Book.fromMap(docSnap.data())));

        return streamListBook;
```

My code is like this.
I also edited Map<String, dynamic> but the problem did not go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Book.fromMap(docSnap.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)` to see if it fixes your issue.